# ffmpeg - Encode audio as list of samples

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, media, signal, audio-conversion

I would like to produce a numeric list of amplitudes from an audio file. I should be able to:

- Specify the sampling rate (16kHz, 44.1kHz, etc)
- Specify the data type of the amplitude samples (8 bit integers, 32 bit floats, etc)
- Easily parse the list so that I can import it into other tools, like Python's numpy (newline delimited, csv, etc)
- *Conversely*, I would also like a method to re-encode such a list into an arbitrary audio format.

I believe I have used ffmpeg to do this before, but haven't been able to find a solution. (Or maybe it was Audacity?)

I think I'm hot on the trail when I look at the set of codecs that my recent-ish ffmpeg supports (edited excerpt from `ffmpeg -codecs`):

```
 DEA..S pcm_f64be            PCM 64-bit floating point big-endian
 DEA..S pcm_s24be            PCM signed 24-bit big-endian
 DEA..S pcm_s64be            PCM signed 64-bit big-endian
 DEA..S pcm_s8               PCM signed 8-bit
 DEA..S pcm_u32be            PCM unsigned 32-bit big-endian
 DEA..S pcm_u8               PCM unsigned 8-bit
```

The above "[PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation)" method seems to describe exactly what I'm trying to do, but I just need to know how to extract the samples in a parseable format.

All the commands that I've tried create files in some binary encoding that seem to require some kind of decoder to understand. Here's an example:

```bsh
ffmpeg -i audio.wav -f u8 -c:a pcm_u8 -ar 16000 out.raw
```

ffmpeg completes this command without issue, but the output is indecipherable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All formats require *some* kind of a parser/decoder, however, the parser needed for the PCM format in your example is actually even simpler than that needed for CSV. `-f u8` is a very straightforward format – "PCM" does not involve any compression, in your case it is literally 1 byte per sample.

This means that various built-in Python and/or Numpy functions can be used to read it. With `u8` (1 byte per sample), you don't need anything extra as Python will already give you a `bytearray` consisting of unsigned integer values:

*Note: All examples are for Python 3.*

```python
with open("out_pcm_u8.raw", "rb") as fh:
    samples = list(fh.read())
```

With formats like `u32be`, you can use the 'struct' or 'array' modules, as well as [numpy.frombuffer()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html). All necessary information is already in the format's name and you just use `help(struct)` to find the matching type (`>` for big-endian, `I` for u32, `i` for s32). For example:

```python
import struct

with open("out_pcm_u32be.raw", "rb") as fh:
    buf = fh.read()
    samples = [t[0] for t in struct.iter_unpack(">I", buf)]
```

```python
import numpy

dt = numpy.dtype(">u4")
with open("out_pcm_u32be.raw", "rb") as fh:
    buf = fh.read()
    samples = numpy.frombuffer(buf, dtype=dt)
```

---

For completeness, the expanded version of the earlier `struct` example:

```python
import struct

samples = []
with open("out_pcm_u32be.raw", "rb") as fh:
    while True:
        buf = fh.read(32 // 8)
        if buf:
            (samp,) = struct.unpack(">I", buf)
            samples.append(samp)
        else:
            break
```

Comment: @t-mart: It just occured to me that Numpy has its own binary data loader, `numpy.frombuffer()`, which could be used for the same purpose.

Comment: As an improvement, from things I just read in the `struct` package:
1. The returned values from `struct` functions are "a tuple even if it contains exactly one item", so `list.extend()` might be better than append to avoid nested data
2. "Creating a Struct object once and calling its methods is more efficient than calling the struct functions with the same format since the format string only needs to be compiled once." Since we're repeating this call for a (large?) file, seems like a good optimization.
3. Also,`Struct` objects expose a `size` property, which is simpler than 32 // 8

Comment: Yes, the struct-using code could be greatly improved for correctness and efficiency; it was mostly meant to demonstrate that it's still a very simple parser (literally a list of samples). The best option seems to be either `array.frombuffer()` which I forgot or `numpy.frombuffer()` which I didn't know previously, either of which should completely avoid creating objects for every sample.

Comment: `array.frombuffer()` unfortunately only uses the native endianness of the current machine. I suppose you could fix this at ffmpeg-time to match your own. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23320951/235992      Numpy types (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) also seem to lack specification of endianness, however you could do something like https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.byteswapping.html#changing-byte-ordering

Comment: Yes, but it still allows you to do `if sys.byteorder != "big": arr.byteswap()`, which is a bit more annoying than having the module take care of it, but ultimately performs the same thing. (Hopefully.)

Comment: As for numpy types, according to the [frombuffer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) docs page, it uses the same way to specify endianness (byte-order) as 'struct' does, i.e. `>` for big-endian. The page shows an example using `newbyteorder(">")`, but it seems you get the same result by directly calling `dtype(">u4")`.